# Can't get pod and service running with generated deployment and service descriptors

Tags: spring, jib

Following Ryan Baxter's [Spring On Kubernetes workshop](https://hackmd.io/@ryanjbaxter/spring-on-k8s-workshop), I run into a problem I can't resolve. On the step of "Deploying To Kubernetes", after generating depoyment.yaml and services.yaml files, I run

```
kubectl apply -f ./k8s
```

and I get validation errors:

```
error validating "k8s/deployment.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "k8s/service.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

After running

kubectl apply -f ./k8s --validate=false

I get

```
error: unable to recognize "k8s/deployment.yaml": no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment
service"my-app" created
```

And here is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/my-id/my-app
        name: my-app
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Based on Harsh's suggestion, I change the apiVersion to apps/v1 and run the kubectl apply command again.

```
deployment "my-app" created
service "my-app" configured
```

Based on what is shown in the watch, I run

```
kubectl port-forward svc/my-app 8080:80
```

where svc/my-app is shown in the watch. And it yields

```
error: invalid resource name svc/my-app: [may not contain '/']
```

To clean up, I run

```
kubectl delete -f ./k8s
```

And it yields

```
service "my-app" deleted
Error from server (NotFound): error when stopping "k8s/deployment.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource
```

I don't know whether those problems are caused by my operations errors or some bugs.

Comment: can you please check the version of kubernetes you are running ? or else please run it like `kubectl apply -f ./k8s --validate=false`

Comment: Thanks. That reminds me that I do see a version difference warning. I didn't recognize that it could be the cause.

Comment: Regarding the "invalid resource name" error, I think your kubectl version is too old.

Comment: Thanks for your information. It is one version older. I resolve the problem with an update.

Answer (score 0):

save this and deploy this file : `kubectl apply -f filename.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: k8s-demo-app
  name: k8s-demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-demo-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: k8s-demo-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: harbor.workshop.demo.ryanjbaxter.com/user1/k8s-demo-app
        name: k8s-demo-app
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: k8s-demo-app
  name: k8s-demo-app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 80-8080
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: k8s-demo-app
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Thanks very much again for your input. I have different access on Docker host so I use Docker Hub. Based on your information, I make a change in the development yaml file (see the updated question). There are still some problems.

Comment: once you appiled YAML file after that checked POD status ? Running or crashing ?

Comment: After I upgrade gcloud components,  kubectl apply -f ./r-k8s --validate=false
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "r-k8s/service.yaml": the server could not find the requested resource
unable to recognize "r-k8s/deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "" But my yaml files are ok.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Harsh and Chanseok, I upgrade gcloud components which kubectl is one of those components.

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:07:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I rerun those commands to deploy the server to the local cluster. It works!

I can't expose the service in the following step, though. An EXTERNAL-IP never shows up after the service.yaml modification. It is another problem.

Comment: The guide you used said "NOTE: `LoadBalancer` features are platform specific. The visibility of your app after changing the service type might depend a lot on where it is deployed (e.g. per cloud provider)." This is indeed true. Based on what you said, I believe you are using GKE (Google Cloud). In many cases, you don't have to expose/assign a public IP of a production cluster. Often you'll use other ways of controlling load balancing and ingress. See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps and https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: @Chanseok Thanks for your input. what I have so far is a local cluster. So, I think the server needs to have an external IP address.

Comment: Local clusters don't and can't have an external IP.